# update table after runing sql query on same page

Tags: jquery, ajax, database

I am running a db query and display the results on the same page. even tho I run the query before I load the page, I have to refresh before it updates my table.  Is there a way to delay the update of the table tell the query finishes?

On the top of the page I have

```
if (isset($_POST['record']))
{
$user->delete($_POST['record'],1);
}
?>
```

Lower in the page I have a table that displays a list of users.  When I delete a user it runs a form

```
echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "\" > " ;
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"action\" value=\"delete\" />";
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"record\" value=\"".$found['id'] ."\" />";
echo "<a id=\"deleteRecord\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash-o\"></i>
```

The table that contains the form is what I need updated.  but after I delete, it loads the table as if the record still exisists.  (it is gone in the database) and I have to do a second refresh before it removes the record.

I also tried do do a refresh as part of isset(POST) and it works sometimes. but I think there must be a better way

Comment: Post some code samples :)

Comment: added some code samples :) Thanks in advance

Comment: Without seeing more of the code I would guess your SELECT query to display the results is being executed before the DELETE query so you have an array of records with the deleted record still there

Comment: How do I accept a comment.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more of the code I would guess your `SELECT` query to display the results is being executed before the `DELETE` query so you have an array of records with the deleted record still there

Perform the `DELETE` query first, then get your records with the `SELECT` query